Как определить числа в составе списка, сумма цифр которых равна N?
Дан список, состоящий из чисел от 1 до 1000. Необходимо определить все числа, цифры которых в сумме дают 13 (67, 76, 931 и т.д.). Понимаю, как это реализовать, если бы было дано одно число (1000, скажем), но в рамках списка непонятно. Пробуй следующий код, но безрезультатно:
n=[i for i in range(1001)]
res=[0 for k in range(1001)]
for i in n:
    while i:
        a=i%10
        i=i//10
        res[k]+=a
        if res[k] == 13:
            print(i)


res делайте просто числом, не массивом, обнуляйте на каждой итерации. На каждой итерации копируйте i в t, и далее работайте с t, чтобы счётчик цикла не менять
n=[i for i in range(1001)]
# или просто for i in range(1001): ?
for i in n:
    t = i
    res = 0
    while t:
        res += t%10
        t //= 10
    if res == 13:
        print(i)

Если диапазон будет больше, то стоит подумать об оптимизации - не проверять все числа, а просто генерировать те числа, для которых сумма цифр равна требуемой

А ведь отличная задача!
Перебор и проверка хорошо работают для небольших n, но можно заметить, что чисел с суммой цифр тринадцать немного. Если в числе ровно k разрядов, то таких чисел не более Сk+1112, что составляет лишь (бесконечно) малую долю от общего количества чисел 9·10k-1. А раз так, то их надо уметь находить без последовательного перебора всех чисел.
Конструировать числа будем последовательно увеличивая их разрядность k - генератор search(k, s, n, d1). Сами числа конструируются от старших разрядов к младшим. При добавлении разряда обновляется s - доступный остаток суммы цифр и n - само число.
Генератор search бесконечный, последовательно вызывает search(k, ...) увеличивая k. Функция main останавливает его, когда очередное число превысило порог.
def search(ss):

    def search(k, s, n, d1):
        if k == 0:
            yield n

        min_d = max(d1, s - 9 * (k - 1))
        max_d = min(9, s)
        for d in range(min_d, max_d + 1):
            yield from search(k - 1, s - d, 10 * n + d, 0)

    k = 1
    while True:
        yield from search(k, ss, 0, 1)
        k += 1


def main():
    s, n = map(int, input().split())
    for i in search(s):
        if i > n:
            break
        print(i)


main()


$ time echo 13 1_000 | python temp.py | wc -l
75

real  0m0.030s
user  0m0.028s
sys   0m0.000s


Прогоны для суммы цифр - тринадцать:



n
время работы
количество чисел




103
0.03 с
75


104
0.03 с
480


105
0.04 с
2205


106
0.05 с
8232


107
0.1 с
26544


108
0.3 с
76560


109
0.6 с
202005


1010
1.5 с
495220


1011
3.5 с
1140920


1012
8.0 с
2491776


1013
17.3 с
5194385


1014
35.7 с
10392760


1015
71.0 с
20048100


1016
143 с
37429104


1017
311 с
67847442


1018
510 с
119739330




Большое вам спасибо

Просто как ещё один вариант эта задача решается короче с использованием встроенных функций питона (но менее оптимально, поскольку работа со строками медленнее, чем работа с числами):
for i in range(1001):
    if sum(map(int, str(i))) == 13:
        print(i)

Или даже в одну строку тот же по сути код:
print(*(i for i in range(1001) if sum(map(int, str(i))) == 13), sep='\n')

Или другой однострочник:
print(*filter(lambda x: sum(map(int, str(x))) == 13, range(1001)), sep='\n')


"менее оптимально" - это не совсем правильно. Последовательное деление работает за квадрат от количества цифр, преобразование в строку (массовое получение цифр числа) можно сделать быстрее (то что в Питоне это не так, там все равно за квадрат, принципа не меняет). По константе один вызов str тоже лучше.

Большое спасибо !
